# Paste specific text and the start and end of every row

Tags: r

I would like to paste in every row at the start and end a specific text

I tried this

```
 d <- c("Mon","Tues","Wednes","Thurs","Fri","Satur","Sun")
 week <- paste("DAY", d, "day", sep="")
```

But it makes only the first part

How is it possible to make?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @RonakShah example DayMonday

Comment: I think your attempt already gives that?

Comment: Maybe `paste0("Day", d, "day")`? Please edit your post with expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want this

```
week <- paste("DAY", paste0(d, "day"), sep="")
```

such that

```
> week
[1] "DAYMonday"    "DAYTuesday"   "DAYWednesday" "DAYThursday" 
[5] "DAYFriday"    "DAYSaturday"  "DAYSunday"
```

Answer (score 1):

Or we can use `sprintf`

```
sprintf("DAY%sday", d)
#[1] "DAYMonday"    "DAYTuesday"   "DAYWednesday" "DAYThursday"  "DAYFriday"    "DAYSaturday"  "DAYSunday"
```

---

Or with `glue`

```
glue::glue("DAY{d}day")
```